# Как запустить консольное приложение c# на сервере

Tags: c#

охайо, написал телеграмм бота который выборочно автопостит из группы вк в канал(вебхуки и обработка сообщений не нужна). Бот написан шарповским консольным приложением. И я вот никак не могу понять как же его исполнить на сервере, чтобы не держать на компьютере включенным 24/7. Гугл не выдает мне ни единого бесплатного сайта где не нужно вводить карты/паспорта. Такие сервисы вообще есть или тут нужны танцы с бубном?

Comment: Для запуска консольного нужен VPS и там запускаете с теми же танцами, что и на локальной машине (.net framework/mono/.net core),

Comment: Вы хотите хостинг за даром?

Comment: Можно офрмить это как Windows Azure Cloud Service и развернуть на Azure. Они предлагают пробный период в объеме 200$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, я бы порекомендовал использовать Windows Service (есть такой тип проектов), на старте службы запускаете своего бота, а остановке - останавливаете.

- Пример, как упростить установку службы -
  https://gist.github.com/alexkuznetsov/b4880005d73ce9decc93a1706394550a
- Пример создания службы - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

UPD. Не совсем понял суть, вам нужен бесплатный хостинг? На счет этого ничего не могу подсказать, мне не попадались бесплатные хостинги на windows.

Вообще, можно глянуть в сторону **OpenShift** от **RedHat**, там есть возможность развертывания **.NET Core** приложений.